# ajax request with javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How should I do to attach directly the params via post method with ajax.updater defined in prototype library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit method used by prototype is `POST` and you got two possibilities to submit post data. Either via the `parameters` option, or via the `postBody` parameter.

```
new Ajax.Updater('id_of_html_to_be_updated', 'url', {
  parameters: {
    id: 1,
    name: "string"
  }
});

// OR

new Ajax.Updater('id_of_html_to_be_updated', 'url', {
  postBody: 'id=1&name=string'
});
```

In the first version prototype converts the `parameters` option to a query string, while in the second example you explicitly state the query string in the `postBody` parameter.

Comment: In my scenario, I have to pass values body as well as parameter in POST Method. What to do now ? Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: @user2959196 it's not clear from your comment if you mean by parameters - URL parameters. If so you can just concatenate those parameters in the URL

Comment: @mhiza Really sorry for putting up a comment in a wrong way. I have to pass two different contents in POST method call. content 1 - pass via body. content 2 - pass via parameters. Both contents has to be supplied in a same AJAX call. HOW TO DO IT ! ! !. Prototype is providing 'postBody' attribute to pass via body. and 'parameter' attribute to pass via url. But I when i add the both content , It is not helping me.

Comment: `new Ajax.Updater('section', '/url?parameter=value', { postBody: content });` ?

Comment: If it is a post method parameter, may i append it directly in the Url like the following **url?parameter=value**

Comment: It would have taken you as much time to test that than comment :|. That's what the source code seems to allow at a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

You supply them via the `parameters` option:

```
new Ajax.Updater('targetId', '/your/url', {
    parameters: {
       foo: "fooValue",
       bar: "barValue"
    }
});
```

See [the docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/) for details; docs for the various common Ajax options are [here](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/). The above updates the element with the ID "targetId" with the results of `POST`ing the parameters `foo` and `bar` to `/your/url`. Because I've supplied the parameters as an object, Prototype handles applying `encodeURIComponent` to them for me.